# Unable to view downloaded WhatsApp images and videos on my Lumia 520

Tags: whatsapp

On my Nokia Lumia 520 I cannot open WhatsApp photos and videos. I deleted all other WhatsApp photos and videos but still I cannot view the images. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you accidentally deleted those images they *should* be in your WhatsApp folder. This folder is in `SDCard > Pictures > WhatsApp`. You can easily access this folder by downloading a Microsoft app called [**Files**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL). With this app you can navigate to every folder and file in your mobile phone.

[image]